# Check value for null

Tags: java, null

I have this Java code which I sue to create Objects into Java List:

```
ListIssues obj = new ListIssues(
                    get.getId(),
                    get.getUrl().toString(),
                    get.getTitle(),
                    get.getState().name(),
                    get.getBody(),
                    get.getMilestone().toString(),
                    get.getLabels().toArray(),
                    get.getCreatedAt(),
                    get.getClosedAt()
                );
```

But for sometimes I have null values. How I can check the values in some smart way?

Comment: Why your `ListIssues` constructor allows null values ? Does n't it throw Exception ?

Comment: It's a very simple Java constructor. I don't know how I can prevent this.

Comment: What's throwing the exception? Code in the constructor, or the code above? (E.g., does `get.getUrl()` sometimes return `null`, and then cause an NPE when you try to call `toString` on it?) Bottom-line is there isn't enough information for us to really help you.

Comment: Agreed. We need to know more about what you want to see. Do you want an exception to be thrown if a null is passed in the constructor, or a default value used, or some other behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> But for sometimes I have null values. How I can check the values in
>   some smart way ?

The good practice is that the `ListIssues` constructor should throw `IllegalArgumentExcetion` if there are any mandatory fields missing (rather than you checking `null` explicitly outside the constructor).

Also, if there are any optional fields that can be set then you can use builder pattern, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

this is kind of hard and can variate according to the application, you should have a validation method that return a boolean with the result of a ***coherent*** validation, and I make emphasis in the word coherent because in some elements like `get.getLabels().toArray()` would be better validate if the array is empty instead of null...

anyways an example:

```
public static boolean isValid(Iget get){
    boolean ret = true;
    ret &= get.getId() !=null;
    ret &= get.getUrl().toString()!=null;
    ...
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Builder pattern for ListIssues class
public class ListIssues {
    private String id, title, url, name, body, milestone, createdAt, closedAt;
    private Array labels[];

    public static class Builder {
        private String id, title, url, name, body, milestone, createdAt, closedAt;
        private Array labels[];

        public Builder withId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withURL(String url) {
            this.url = url;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withBody(String body) {
            this.body = body;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMilestone(String milestone) {
            this.milestone = milestone;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withClosedAt(String closedAt) {
            this.closedAt = closedAt;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withLabels(Array[] labels) {
            this.labels = labels;
            return this;
        }

        public ListIssues build() {
            return new ListIssues(this);
        }
    }

    private ListIssues(Builder b) {
        this.id = b.id;
        this.title = b.title;
        this.url = b.url;
        this.name = b.name;
        this.body = b.body;
        this.milestone = b.milestone;
        this.createdAt = b.createdAt;
        this.closedAt = b.closedAt;
        this.labels = b.labels;
    }}

        // Now you can check for null input parameters using ternary operators before you create the object.
    ListIssues listIssues = new ListIssues.Builder()
    .withURL(get.getUrl() == null ? "" : get.getUrl().toString())
    .withMilestone(get.getMilestone() == null ? "":get.getMilestone().tpString())
.withBody(get.getBody())
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still unclear to some degree, so I don’t know whether this answers it, but I wanted to mention I typically write my constructors something like this:

```
public ListIssues(String id, String url, String title, String state,
        Body body, String milestone, String[] labels, Instant createdAt,
        Instant closedAt) {
    super();
    this.id = Objects.requireNonNull(id);
    this.url = Objects.requireNonNull(url);
    this.title = Objects.requireNonNull(title);
    this.state = Objects.requireNonNull(state);
    this.body = Objects.requireNonNull(body);
    this.milestone = Objects.requireNonNull(milestone);
    this.labels = Objects.requireNonNull(labels);
    this.createdAt = Objects.requireNonNull(createdAt);
    this.closedAt = Objects.requireNonNull(closedAt);
}
```

`requireNonNull()` will throw a `NullPointerException` if the argument is null. If one argument is allowed to be null, just leave out the call.